# My Android App shows up twice in list when sharing from the Photos App

Tags: android, image, share, photos

My Android app has the ability to receive both URL and Image shares from other apps.  The following extract from the manifest shows the definition of the two activities involved in handling these shares:

```
  <!-- Activity: Share Handler -->
  <activity android:name="com.softframeworks.tabdancer.ShareHandlerActivity"
            android:label="@string/shared_browser_url"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    <!-- Intent filter indicates that this activity can handle text -->
    <!-- shared using the SEND action.                              -->
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" android:priority="777">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <!-- Activity: Image Share Handler -->
  <activity android:name="com.softframeworks.tabdancer.edit.icon_cache.ImageShareHandlerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:parentActivityName="com.softframeworks.tabdancer.ManageActivity">
    <!-- Intent filter indicates that this activity can handle images -->
    <!-- shared using the SEND action.                                -->
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

The problem I am having is that when sharing a photo from the Google Photos app, my app shows up twice.  It seems that the intent-filter of both of my activities matches with whatever the Photos app can share to.  I would like my app to show up only once in the list of those that can receive shares from the Photo app.  Ideally, the share would be done as an image (not URL).

I am testing this on a Nexus 7 running Marshmallow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by changing my manifest to be as follows:

```
  <!-- Activity: Share Handler -->
  <activity android:name="com.softframeworks.tabdancer.ShareHandlerActivity"
            android:label="@string/shared_browser_url"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
    <!-- Intent filter indicates that this activity can handle text shared -->
    <!-- using the SEND action.                                            -->
    <!-- Intent filter also indicates that this activity can handle images -->
    <!-- shared using the SEND action.  However the code for this activity -->
    <!-- redirects image shares to the ImageShareHandlerActivity.          -->
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" android:priority="777">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
      <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <!-- Activity: Image Share Handler -->
  <activity android:name="com.softframeworks.tabdancer.edit.icon_cache.ImageShareHandlerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:parentActivityName="com.softframeworks.tabdancer.ManageActivity">
  </activity>
```

So now the ShareHandlerActivity handles image as well as text shares.  However, in this activity's onCreate() method I test the intent's type.  If it's image/* then I delegate the processing of the share to the ImageShareHandlerActivity.